# DITA OT: Missing conditional text from PDF output

Tags: pdf, dita, dita-ot

I'm migrating a custom PDF plugin from DITA OT 2.4.4 to 2.5.4. It worked fine in DITA 2.4.4, but in 2.5.4, some elements are missing from the output. I've been able to work around this by adding templates for the missing elements to the custom plugin. The one I haven't been able to fix is for conditions to the body text (such as using the product attribute like ). Conditions are correctly included and excluded in the title, but not in the body of the topic.

I've looked in the provided org.dita.pdf2 plugins, but I can't find where conditions are filtered. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The filtering of DITA elements based on filters specified in the DITAVAL files is not done in the XSLT code, it's done in Java pre-processing steps.
So if your PDF plugin defines a separate transformation type and has ANT build files, maybe you could try to update those, if you copied ANT targets from the base PDF plugin, try to see how they changed. But it depends really on your particular PDF plugin, most PDF plugins which contribute a transformation type only use it to specify a PDF customization folder in the custom ANT build file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at my plugin and build files. I'm using the build_preprocess.xml from org.dita.base. The plugin doesn't have its own build file, but adds some conditions in the integrator.xml file, such as:

```
<!-- [Kofax] 2016-Apr-14 MAS: Passes through the command-line parameter for selecting the branding and sets
corporate as the default. -->
<condition property="title.branding" value="${title.branding}" else="corporate">
  <isset property="title.branding"/>
</condition>    
  </target>
```

The plugin also has a root-processing.xsl file that has overrides to update the PDF's metadata.

Is there somewhere else I should look in my plugin?

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: This shouldn't've been included as an answer unless you were actually answering your own question. If this information contributes to clarifying the question then it should be added there in an edit.